# How to correct Spanish orthographic spelling errors in file names

Tags: filemanager, spell-checking

I am using Ubuntu Studio 20.04.

I wonder if there is some app to automatically correct the "normal" Spanish language orthographic errors/mistakes in the file names of any folder in the hard disk.

I'm talking about something like the internal automatic spell-checking of LibreOffice, but in the file manager GUI.

Comment: I've never seen an app like that, but you could copy all the file names to a new text file from the terminal and then open the text file in LibreOffice Writer and use Writer's spell-checking feature to spell-check the file names. It wouldn't be too time-consuming to do it that way if there weren't too many orthographic spelling errors that needed to be corrected.

Comment: @karel I understand your process. But... When the LibreOffice spell-checking ends its job... How can I put the corrected names list into the files manager, again? ???

Comment: If there aren't too many orthographic spelling errors that need to be corrected it wouldn't take too long to rename the file names one at a time manually. You can automate this process by installing gprename with `sudo apt install gprename` which adds context menu renaming functionality to files file manager, including renaming multiple files according to a search expression.

Comment: Here is an example of batch renaming multiple files. I have a group of text files in the same directory. I want to open all of them in LibreOffice writer to change them from plain text into formatted text. First I select all the files, copy them and paste them. This creates multiple new files named like old_file (copy).txt, etc. Then I batch rename the copies from like old_file (copy).txt to a form like old_file.odt.

Comment: Thanks @kaerl. I will test the gprename to perform the corrections.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen an app like that, but you could copy all the file names to a new text file from the terminal and then open the text file in LibreOffice Writer and use Writer's spell-checking feature to spell-check the file names. It wouldn't be too time-consuming to do it that way if there weren't too many orthographic spelling errors that needed to be corrected.

If there aren't too many orthographic spelling errors that need to be corrected it wouldn't take too long to rename the file names one at a time manually. You can automate this process by installing gprename with `sudo apt install gprename` which adds context menu renaming functionality to Files file manager, including renaming multiple files in the same directory according to find and replace expressions.

Here is an example of batch renaming multiple files. I have a group of text files in the same directory. I want to open all of them in LibreOffice writer to change them from plain text into formatted text. First I select all the files, copy them and paste them. This creates multiple new files named like old_file (copy).txt, etc. Then I batch rename the copies from like old_file (copy).txt to a form like old_file.odt by replacing `(copy).txt` with `.odt` for all of the selected files together.